# Mixed Hodge structures over $F\otimes \mathbb{R}$

Tags: reference-request, l-functions, mixed-hodge-structure

Let $F$ be a number field. Nekovàř, on page 18 of [Values of L-functions and p-adic cohomology](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jan.nekovar/pu/ecm.pdf), is referring to the category of mixed Hodge structures over $F\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$. Can anyone precise the definition of the above?

Many thanks!